# can I switch NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, switch-statement

I want to switch NSString in XmlParser because if there are 15 or more web-service then every time the loop check for correct element in IF..ELSE.That I don't want to make processor busy..

I have searched a lot and found using enum I can switch NSString but no luck ..
I have tried each possibilities,but some where i am making mistake.
Please help to solve this big problem for me.

Here I have declare my enum:

[image: Here I have declare my enum]

Here in "elementName" I am getting Exact value as declared in enum:

[image: Here in "elementName" I am getting Exact value as declared in enum]

But instead of `1`, I am getting wrong value Like `202896536`:

[image: But instead of "1" I am getting wrong value Like'202896536']

Comment: Paste your codes instead of screenshot wherever possible !

Comment: @Raptor yes,but just for debug-info I have placed screenshot so developer can understand properly.

Comment: the question is far beyond casting an integer. You're parsing a XML and the `elementName` is the tag name. You should get the content in the XML tag instead of tag name, right?

Comment: WebServiceList isn't NSString .. relevant titles make a big difference in the up/down votes received.

Comment: @Raptor  what should I do if there is more then 25 WebService then for each elementName it will look in every if statment..so is it right tecnique to write if statment for each elementname?

Comment: see my answer. the array in App delegate should store what you parse from XML.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it by creating enum. You must need to compare the string.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"UserLoginComplexType"])
     //Do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** cast a string to ENUM value, you will need to parse it, ENUM values are integers not strings.

You will have to use an `if` statement.

You could use a helper method:

**WebServiceList.h**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, WebServiceList) {
    WebServiceListNone = 0,
    UserLoginComplexType = 1,
    RegisterUserResult = 2,
    RecoverPasswordResult = 3,
    ....
};

FOUNDATION_EXTERN WebServiceList WebServiceListForString(NSString *string);
```

**WebServiceList.m**

```
WebServiceList WebServiceListForString(NSString *string) {
    WebServiceList list = WebServiceListNone;

    if (![type isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    return CallRecordTypeNone;
    }
    else if ([string isEqualToString:@"UserLoginComplexType"] {
    list = UserLoginComplexType;
    }
    else if ([string isEqualToString:@"UserLoginComplexType"]) {
    list = UserLoginComplexType;
    }
    else .....

    return list;
 }
```

Comment: ya..i am using if statement.but in case of Web-service >25  .my thread become busy and app hangs for few seconds...

Comment: The run the parsing in the background, there is no other solution since there is no way around the `if` statement since you can not cast a string to one of the enum value.

Comment: ya ..I am using the Exact Method  as you have mentioned. Thanks for value able time ..I will meet you soon on chat room if u want

Answer (score 0):

As seen in your commented codes, you're parsing a XML and saving in a `NSMutableArray` named `arrProductList` in App Delegate.

After finishing the parsing of XML, the variable should contain the data in array. You should look into the variable & fetch the corresponding value. Since you didn't post any further details about parsing / XML structure, I'm unable to write some codes related to result fetching.

Answer (score 0):

For easy readability and to avoid lots of if-else statements, I like to do mine as a dictionary:

(also makes it easy to update in the future when you add more to your enum)

```
NSString* elementName = ...;

//  Default value
WebServiceList value = UserLoginComplexType;

NSDictionary* stringToEnum = @{@"UserLoginComplexType":@(UserLoginComplexType),
                               @"RegisterUserResult":@(RegisterUserResult),
                               @"RecoverPasswordResult":@(RecoverPasswordResult)};

NSNumber* enumValue = stringToEnum[elementName];

if(enumValue != nil)
    value = (WebServiceList)enumValue.integerValue;
```